# Is using the IP address faster than using the domain name?

Tags: networking, dns, ip

Assuming that the IP address that the domain is mapped to is known, are there any advantages to using this known IP address rather than using the domain? What makes the trace routing decision? Because DNS servers translate the domain names to IP addresses I am compelled to say that using an IP address is quicker, albeit unnoticeable. However, because DNS servers process these requests at a high volume and presumably cache the most popular sites I am also compelled to say that a DNS server might know the fastest route to the server which would result in the domain being slightly quicker. I understand that when I am asking which may be faster this quantification may be at the nanosecond or microsecond scale.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Technically, yes. At least the first time. The first time your computer asks the internet "Where is this domain name located?" and some machine out there responds with its IP address.
However, when it gets this response back it keeps a copy (called caching) so it doesn't have to ask again for a while (these things CAN change, but rarely do)

So, if your computer currently has the IP cached, then they are equal. If you don't currently have it IP is faster, but only for the first time in a few days and only a few seconds

As for the question of how the fastest route is picked. There are several routing protocols, most of which take into account several different factors including load on a connection, bandwidth, latency, jitter, and distance. Several others are also possible. Long story short is that the routers of the internet are constantly telling each other that such and such link is down or I just got a new address connected and they have algorithms that the routers run to figure out which way is best.

N.B. A side note is that IP wont always give you access to a certain website: take for instance a site hosted on a hosting service. They rarely have their own specific IP address, but instead requests for lots of different sites could come into one IP. In this case the domain name being requested is used to determine which site to return to the requester

Answer (score 4):

Both of the examples that you gave are correct. Inputting an IP address directly will bypass the need for a DNS lookup, but the advantage you gain by doing this could be pointless if you use an IP address to a popular website which brings you halfway around the world instead of to a server nearby. Ultimately, you wouldn't benefit enough to make it worth your while, especially since your computer will cache the response you receive from the DNS lookup, making the difference 0.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered pretty well by @PsychoData but I think there's a few things worth noting and restating here:

- When using IP, you bypass DNS which will save you the DNS resolution time on the first call until the TTL (Time To Live) expires. TTL is usually 1 hour. The difference is usually not worth noticing in most applications. If you're only making one call, you won't notice the milliseconds delay. If you make multiple calls, all calls after the first won't have the delay.
- When entering a name vs IP you can be calling several different Networking daemons including NetBIOS (\ServerX), DNS FQDN (\ServerX.domain.com), DNS Shortname (\ServerX which *MAY* get automatically lengthened or guessed to the FQDN \ServerX.domain.com by your OS or DNS server)
- Microsoft has two primary Authentication Mechanisms in play with SMB shares: NTLMv2 (NTLMv1 and CHAP are insecure) and Kerberos. Depending on lots of configurations on your client, the server, and the authentication server (Active Directory if in play) and the way you called the name, you may get one or the other. Kerberos is generally faster than NTLMv2, at least for repeated calls, as it gets and keeps an authentication token and doesn't need to reauthenticate via password hash each time.
- NetBIOS uses different ports than DNS which can play into network latency due to ACLs/routers/Firewalls.
- NetBIOS can actually give you a different answer than DNS because it's a different resolution system. Generally the first PC to boot on a subnet will act as the NetBIOS server and a new server can randomly declare itself to the network as the new NetBIOS master. Also \FileShareServer.domain.com wouldn't come back in a NetBIOS lookup as it's not the machine name (ServerX) but a DNS alias.

There's probably even more that I'm missing here but I think you get the idea that a lot of factors can be in play here.